# Element insertion is not reflecting during jquery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Am trying to create a DIV with image inside another DIV for showing AJAX processing.Am doing it in JQUERY AJAX "beforeSend". What happens is, the image am inserting get visible only after the AJAX call. I have inspected the DOM, the insertion is happening in "beforeSend" but gets visible after AJAX call. below is the piece of code

```
options.beforeSend = function(jqXHR, settings){ 
    $('#'+_divId).prepend(jQuery('<div/>', {
        class : 'ajax-progress'
    }).append(jQuery('<img/>').attr('src',"/images/ajax.gif")));
}
```

I thought the image download has the problem. so i tried having the div in DOM with "display:none" and detaching it using jQuery and inserted in "beforeSend". but no use.

```
$('#'+_divId).prepend(
$('#imageDiv').detach());
```

I cant do it in "ajaxStart".

Comment: if this feature is for a specific page and functionality, then why you are using beforeSend. Is it possible to do this prepend and append before AJAX call manually? usually beforeSend is used to add extra headers or other information to the request.

Comment: not specific to a page, we have done some extra stuff in beforeSend and this is a new one. am trying to do in a generic way otherwise each screen and each ajax call we need to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the reason. It is not working in AJAX call with attribute "async : false".

As AJAX is made synchronous, the DOM updates are suspended till call gets complete.